# attach same addins but from different folders on Excel start up

Tags: c++, excel, batch-file, xll

I have a Excel addin XLL that is written in C++, say it is called abc.xll.

What I would like to do is to write a little batch script so that when I call it to start with "Prod" parameter it will launch the Excel with the xll addin in the C:\xllProduction\abc.xll folder and when I start it with the "Dev" parameter it will launch Excel xll in the C:\xllDev\abc.xll folder.

I know I can use set local in .bat file to force the environmental variable to be effective for a particular session only, and I can use start excel to start Excel, but I am not sure how to start with a particular xll.

I am using Excel 2010 if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to fix the registry entries that Excel uses to pick up XLLs in your launch script. Take a look at this answer for tips: [How to deploy an Excel XLL Add-In and automatically register the Add-In in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602560/how-to-deploy-an-excel-xll-add-in-and-automatically-register-the-add-in-in-excel)